# Custom CTypes: Position in type dropdown

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

Is there a "quick" way to change the sort order of new content elements in the type dropdown? It seems, that new content elements are pushed to the end of the array, so they appear at the end of the list.

**Current position (at the end of list):**

[image]

**Should be:**

At the end of group "Standard".

[image]

**Question:**

Is is possible to register a content element to a specific group like "Standard" or "Lists" or a new group?

---

P.S.: Content element registered correctly in TCA/Overrides/tt_content and in Page TS Config for Wizard. Let me know if the code should be relevant, I will add it then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try out `ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem()` and see argument #3 and #4.

If I want to add a custom group at a certain position, I usually loop over `$GLOBALS[TCA][tt_content][CType][config][items]` and place it in the right position, if the API is not sufficient in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can add new groups using `ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItemGroup()`.

For example,

```
ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItemGroup(
    'tt_content',
    'CType',
    'my_new_group',
    'Label for my group',
    'after:default'
);
```

Other possibilities for position are `before:some_group_id`, `bottom`, and `top`.

Then there is an optional fourth array value in the `$item` parameter for `ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem()` which allows you to specify which group you are adding to.

The fourth and fifth parameters to `addTcaSelectItem()` allow you to specify a position relative to another item in the drop-down.

```
ExtensionManagementUtility::addTcaSelectItem(
    'tt_content',
    'CType',
    ['Label for my item', 'my_new_item', 'my-item-icon', 'my_new_group'],
    'some_other_item',
    'after'
);
```

The "Standard" group is called `default`. If you reuse an existing group ID, `addTcaSelectItemGroup()` will return without changing anything.